# How to make a <input type="password"> disappear

Tags: html

So this is my first question. I'm very new to coding, and only have done a few basic programs, so please don't judge me if the answer is obvious. Me and my friend have worked together to create a chat app. We are currently making a password for the program because right now, anyone with the url can join. I am already aware of `<input type="password>` and I have made a little program using it, but what I want to do is to make this code more secure/make other code appear and the button and password disappear. (This is the program I was talking about)

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
    <body>  
        <script> 
            function pswChecker(){
                var psw = document.getElementById("psw").value; 
                if(psw == "password") {
                    alert("Code goes here.");
                } else {
                    window.close();
                }
            }   
        </script>
        <div class="fadeMe">
        <div> 
        <div style="color=white;">What is the password?</div>
            <input type="text" id="psw" name="psw">
            <input type="button" value="Submit" id="submit" onClick="pswChecker()"> 
        </div>
    </body> 
 </html>
```

Comment: This is definitely not secure as anybody looking at the page source will see what the password is that they need to input. The only way to make this process secure is to send (POST) the password to some server-side processing mechanism. You will almost certainly need to learn some server-side coding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keeping your password inside of HTML source is not secure and everyone who can access your website can see the password. Since you are working on a chat application I assume you have some sort of a server - you will have to perform checks on the back end.

To hide an element you can add an ID to it and use the following code:

```js
const passwordDiv = document.getElementById("password");
const hideButton = document.getElementById("hide");

hideButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
    passwordDiv.style.display = 'none';
});
```

```html
<div id="password">
The password form goes here.
<button id="hide">Hide</button>
</div>
```

If you want to show something else you can use the same code but set the display to `block` instead.

Answer (score 0):

To add a style which is what I think you want you can do something like this.

```
document.getElementsByClassName("fadeMe").style.display = "none";
```